# Mid acting sketchy reads some things but not others (Closed)

Tags: vb.net

ok so this is part of a bigger program, this part reads a string from a local IP and cuts it up to display the parts

this is the code in the sub (some ''s for testing stuff and future use)
EVERYTHING WORKS EXCEPT SolDig and SolAnl1
i use txtSerialText to see the output

sHTML - the file it is reading from the IP is like this (actual sample)
Temperature: 22.36 [C] Humidity: 56.23 [%] Pressure: 98580 [Pa] SolAnl1: 1023 SolDig: 1 BattVolt: 0

now no matter how i adjust the parameters example- SolDigPos + 5, 2 for the mid command it will not read those 2 settings. i can get Soldig: ldig: ig: : even if i change it to read 10 instead of 2 i can not get the 1 after SolDig: or the 1023 after SolAnl1:

in the SolAnl1Pos and SolDigPos lines i have tried with and without the : in them

Again all the other MIDs work fine even the BattVolt at the end

am i missing something? any help would be appreciated

CODE:

```
    Dim TempC As String
    Dim TempF As String
    Dim Hum As String
    Dim PresP As String
    Dim PresC As String
    Dim Pres As String
    Dim TempPos As String
    Dim HumPos As String
    Dim PresPos As String
    Dim WSBattPOS As String
    Dim WSBattLvl As String
    Dim SolAnl1 As String
    Dim SolDig As String
    Dim SolAnl1Pos As String
    Dim SolDigPos As String

    Dim sHTML As String = " "
    Dim URL As String = "http://192.168.0.126"

    Dim web_client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient, Info As String = ""
    Dim response As IO.Stream, stream_reader As IO.StreamReader

    response = web_client.OpenRead(URL)
    stream_reader = New IO.StreamReader(response)
    Info = stream_reader.ReadToEnd()                        ' Read the result.
    sHTML = Info
    stream_reader.Close() ' Close the stream reader and its underlying stream.
    response.Close()

    TempPos = InStr(1, sHTML, "Temp", 0)
    HumPos = InStr(1, sHTML, "Hum", 0)
    PresPos = InStr(1, sHTML, "Pres", 0)
    WSBattPOS = InStr(1, sHTML, "BattVolt", 0)
    SolAnl1Pos = InStr(1, sHTML, "SolAnl1:", 0)
    SolDigPos = InStr(1, sHTML, "SolDig:", 0)

    TempCLbl.Text = Mid(sHTML, TempPos + 13, 5)
    TempFLbl.Text = (TempCLbl.Text * 1.8) + 32
    HumLbl.Text = Mid(sHTML, HumPos + 10, 5)
    PresP = Mid(sHTML, PresPos + 10, 5)
    PresC = PresP / 3386.389
    BPresLbl.Text = Mid(PresC, 1, 6)
    WSBattLbl.Text = Mid(sHTML, WSBattPOS + 11, 4)


    SolAnl1 = Mid(sHTML, SolAnl1Pos + 8, 5)
    SolDig = Mid(sHTML, SolDigPos + 5, 2)
    'txtSerialText2.Text = Mid(sHTML, SolAnl1Pos + 6, 5)
    'PMoistBar1.Value = Mid(sHTML, SolAnl1Pos + 6, 5)

    TempC = TempCLbl.Text
    TempF = TempFLbl.Text
    Hum = HumLbl.Text
    Pres = BPresLbl.Text
    WSBattLvl = WSBattLbl.Text
    'SolAnl1 = PMoistBar1.Value

    txtSerialText2.Text = sHTML
    txtSerialText.Text = SolDig
```

END CODE:

I've tried altering the parameters for where it starts and how much it reads
google searching gave me loads of stuff on the MID command and it shows to do what I'm doing (that works fine on the rest of the string)

Comment: Set `Option Strict` to `ON` ASAP (yes, there might be *a couple of things* to fix after)

Comment: That code looks like it was written for VB6. I'm guessing that you learned from someone who was a VB6 developer and never bothered to really learn VB.NET properly. If you're going to use .NET then you should use .NET. That would mean using `String.IndexOf` rather than `InStr` and `String.Substring` rather than `Mid`. Those are both holdovers from VB6. Declaring two variables on the same line is a very VB6 thing to do as well.

Comment: update by reprogramming the arduino making the sHTML file to change SolAnl1 and SolDig to SoilA and SoilD and changing the lines in my program         SolAnl1Pos = InStr(1, sHTML, "SoilA", 0)
        SolDigPos = InStr(1, sHTML, "SoilD:", 0)      now reads SoilA correctly only SoilD reads incorrectly, and since i wasnt sure if i was going to use it anyway as I am more interested in the analog, I'm going to call this "works well enough" Thanks for all the help. I'll close this now